# How do I enable Terminal's color highlighting in OS X for root?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal

I've added the following lines to my .bash_profile at /Users/[my username] :

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=ExFxCxDxBxegedabagacad
```

And it works fine. However, when I did the same for root's .bash_profile at /var/root it doesn't work. Any ideas why this doesn't work for root?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I know I'm supposed to use sudo. ;-) Nonetheless, I still would like to know how to enable this for root.

Comment: My root user's shell is `/bin/sh` according to `dscl`. Maybe that's the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can toss those into `~/.profile` or source the relevant file from `~/.profile` inside the home directory for the root user, and then log in via `sudo su -` to simulate a full login. It works for me on BASH on Snow Leopard.

As a side note, I define the alias, `alias ls='ls -G'`, in my .bashrc files to enable colour output for `ls`.

Comment: Changed the name of .bash_profile of root to .profile as you suggested and now it works beautifully. However, .bash_profile works for other users though. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following into the /var/root/.bashrc file:

```
export PS1="\[\033[03;31m\][\u@\h\[\033[03;37m\] \W \[\033[03;31m\]]\\$ \[\033[00m\]"
alias grep='grep --color'
export CLICOLOR='yes'
TERM=xterm-color
```

Being root, type the following:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

Exit and 'sudo su' back to root.